# Windows forms - wait until form is completely drawn (painted)

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, showdialog

I designed a for wich only objective is to run an method.
It's a `please wait` form.

I give a delegate to it, and call `ShowDialog`.
It just takes that delegate and executes it in the `Shown` event. After that, `Hide()`.

The purpose is solely to be there telling user to wait until delegate is run.

BUT: It starts executing the delegate BEFORE it's completely show. I mean, the form appears in the screen, but the `please wait` label gets stuck by the running code, being shown very late, or even not shown. (An empty rectangle remains in the middle of the form).

I could make form wait maybe two seconds before running the delegate, but is there another way (better and assured) to call the delegate AFTER the form is completely painted, with label shown???

Thanks.

Comment: "the form appears in the screen, but the please wait label gets stuck by the running code, being shown very late, or even not shown. (An empty rectangle remains in the middle of the form)."  Sounds like you need to execute the delegate in a **separate thread** so that the Form can display and update itself properly.

Comment: Call this.Update() before running the delegate.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, would the separate thread be slower??? That's heavy main code.

Comment: You can call Update() like Hans suggests, and you might even need to sprinkle some Application.DoEvents() in there to allow the form to refresh itself...but if the process is "heavy" enough to prevent the form from updating then the "correct" way to handle it is with a background thread.  If you want a better answer then show us some code.

Comment: The code is just that: form shown calls delegate and hide. Two lines.

Comment: That Update() seems to work!! Thanks!! Someone did a thread inversion in this question to keep heavy code in main thread and UI in background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155628/visual-basic-net-how-to-create-a-thread-to-update-the-ui

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)   The BackgroundWorker component has 4 events.

You would need to implement 2 of them: DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted

The DoWork method executes in a thread, and is where you do your work ( or in your case, call your delegate) 
The RunWorkerCompleted is called when the work is finished, and you can call your Hide() method there.

If you happen to want to show Progress, you can Implement the ProgressChanged event, which allows you to pass in a percentage completed and an object ( normally I pass a message on what I'm doing )

Then just do your Drawing like normal, and call the Background worker RunWorkerAsync to get it called.

```
public class Wait : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker _bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
    public delegate void toExecuteDele(object args); 

    public toExecuteDele ToExecute; 

    public Wait()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        _bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( DoWork )
        _bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler (WorkDone); 
    }  

    public void Execute(object args)
    {
         // Display Stuff (label, start a progress bar pulsing, maybe enable disable stuff 
            DispalyStuff(" Plate Wait"); 
         _bgWorker.RunBackgroundAsync(args); 
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

         if( ToExecute != null )
            ToExecute(e.Argument); 

    }  

    public void WorkDone(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {  
        // Display an Error if there is an exception in the event args 
        Hide(); 
    }
}
```

Everything in the DoWork happens in another thread, Everything else you do runs in the UI thread, and wont hang up while executing.